# Derivative of matrix w.r.t. its own vectorized version

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, vectorization

I am unable to find what would be the derivative of a $m \times m$ real matrix $A$ with respect to $(\mathrm{vec}(A))^T$ (where $T$ is transpose and $\mathrm{vec}$ stacks the columns) without using tensors (i.e. remaining in 2d notation). I assume it would involve the Kronecker product, but is there a straightforward answer, or a convention?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Can you expand what you mean by $vec(A)$ and how you intend to take a derivative ``with respect to $(vec(A))^T$''?

Comment: You want the derivative of the "anti-vectorization" (linear) function that takes an $n^2$-vector and produces an $n \times n$ matrix. If you want to use neither tensors nor $3$ subscripts, then simply compute the derivative of each of the $n^2$ scalar fields with respect to the $n^2$-vector, each of which will be a gradient vector. Expect lots, *lots* of zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing row $k$ of $\mu$ as a row vector $\mu_{k}$, we obtain
$$\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu
=\left[\matrix{
\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_1 \\
\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_2 \\
\vdots \\
\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_m \\
}\right]
=\left[\matrix{
\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_{11} & \dots & \partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_{1m} \\
& \vdots \\
\partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_{m1} & \dots & \partial_{\mathrm{vec}(\mu)^T}\mu_{mm} \\
}\right]
=[I_mI_m \dots I_m]$$

where the last display is a block matrix of $m$-by-$m$ identity matrices.

Answer (score 4):

$\def\bb{\mathbb}$
You don't want to use tensors, but they can be quite illuminating.

A matrix and its vectorized form are related by
$$a = {\rm vec}(A) \quad\iff\quad A={\rm Mat}(a)$$
This can alternatively be written using third-order
$\bb V$ectorization/$\bb M$atricization tensors and single/double dot products
$$\eqalign{
a &= \bb V:A \quad\iff\quad &A=\bb M\cdot a \\
a &= A:\bb M \quad\iff\quad &A=a\cdot\bb V \\
}$$
The gradient of a matrix with respect to itself yields the fourth-order identity tensor
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial A} = \bb E\quad\implies\quad X =(\bb E:X)=(X:\bb E)$$
just as the gradient of a vector wrt itself yields the second-order identity matrix
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial a} = I\quad\implies\quad x =(I\cdot x)=(x\cdot I)$$
Using these tensors, one can write the vector-by-vector, matrix-by-vector, and vector-by-matrix gradients in terms of the matrix-by-matrix gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial a}{\partial b} 
  &= \frac{\partial(\bb V:A)}{\partial(B:\bb M)} 
  &= \bb V:&\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right):\bb M \\
\frac{\partial A}{\partial b} 
  &= \frac{\partial A}{\partial(B:\bb M)} 
  &= &\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right):\bb M \\
\frac{\partial a}{\partial B} 
  &= \frac{\partial(\bb V:A)}{\partial B} 
  &= \bb V:&\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}\right) \\
}$$
Combining the above ideas yields
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial A}{\partial a} 
  &= \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial A}\right):\bb M 
  &= (\bb E):\bb M  = \bb M \\
\frac{\partial a}{\partial A} 
  &= \bb V:\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial A}\right) 
  &= \bb V:(\bb E)  = \bb V \\
}$$
So how are these tensors defined?

For matrices in $\;\bb R^{m\times n}\;$ they are
$$\eqalign{
\bb V_{\ell jk} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;\ell+m=j+mk \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
\bb M_{jk\ell} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;j-1={\rm div}(\ell-1,n)\;\;\&\;\;k-1={\rm mod}(\ell-1,n) \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
\bb E_{jkpq} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;j=p\;\;\&\;\;k=q \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
I_{jp} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;j=p \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
and the index ranges are
$$\eqalign{
1&\le\; j,p  \;&\le m
 &\qquad\big({\rm the}\,row\;{\rm index}\big) \\
1&\le\; k,q  \;&\le n
 &\qquad\big({\rm the}\,column\;{\rm index}\big) \\
1&\le\; \ell \;&\le m\!\cdot\!n
 &\qquad\big({\rm the}\,long\;{\rm index}\big) \\
}$$
In some sense the third-order tensors are the more fundamental quantities,
since given $\big(\bb M,\bb V\big)$
the remaining tensors can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\bb E &= \bb M\cdot\bb V
  \qquad&\big({\rm contract\,over\,long\,index}\big) \\
I &= \bb V:\bb M
  \qquad&\big({\rm contract\,over\,row/column\,indexes}\big) \\
}$$
Similarly, $I$ is more fundamental than $\bb E$ since
$$\eqalign{
{\bb E}_{jkpq} &= I_{jp}I_{kq} \\
}$$
Also note that you only need to calculate one of the fundamental tensors,
since they are equal after a cyclic rotation of the indexes
$$\eqalign{
{\bb M}_{jk \ell} &\doteq {\bb V}_{\ell jk} \\
}$$
The definition of $\bb V$ being somewhat simpler, is usually the tensor
which is chosen.

Comment: I have a related question: how to perform some matrix operations **directly** in the vectorized space without reshaping the matrix? If you have any answer, here is my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4026722/does-there-exist-a-way-to-compute-matrix-properties-eigenvalues-determinant/4026729?noredirect=1#comment8313472_4026729