# About standard vectorization of a matrix and its derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, vectorization

I read about this notation: if $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ then $X^b \in \mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ is the standard vectorization of $X$. I searched the term "standard vectorization" and only found results about vectorization, for example this [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). So the first part of the question is simply a clarification of the notation. For instance, if $X = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ then $X^b = [a\ b\ c\ d]$ or $[a\ c\ b\ d]$ or even something completely different?

Assuming that it's one of the two first, I don't understand how it is useful. Isn't just another way to view the same thing? Could you provide some examples that demonstrate its purpose?

Finally, as stated in the question, I am interesting in understanding how to calculate the derivative wrt the vectorization. For instance, let $f: \mathbb{R}^{d\times d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a function. What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^b}$? I know how to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$ so my first try was to use the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^b} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial X^b}$$

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106779/derivative-of-matrix-w-r-t-its-own-vectorized-version) which seems relevant but I think that something is wrong because if $\frac{\partial X}{\partial X^b}$ is $[I_d I_d \dots I_d]$ then the dimensions don't match to perform matrix multiplication.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a matrix-valued function $F$ of a matrix-valued variable $X$, e.g.
$$F = X^3$$
rather than jumping straight to the chain rule
consider its *differential*
$$dF = dX\,X^2 + X\,dX\,X + X^2\,dX$$
Use vectorization on this differential expression to obtain
$${\rm vec}(dF)
 = \Big((X^2)^T\otimes I\;+\;X^T\otimes X\;+\;I\otimes X^2\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dX)
$$
Then the gradient of the vectorized function is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(X)}
 &= (X^2)^T\otimes I\;+\;X^T\otimes X\;+\;I\otimes X^2
}$$
Index notation is another option
$$\eqalign{
dF_{i\ell}
 &= dX_{ij}\,X^2_{j\ell} + X_{ij}\,dX_{jk}\,X_{k\ell}
  + X^2_{ik}\,dX_{k\ell} \\
\frac{\partial F_{i\ell}}{\partial X_{pq}}
 &= (\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq})\,X^2_{j\ell}
  + X_{ij}\,(\delta_{jp}\delta_{kq})\,X_{k\ell}
  + X^2_{ik}\,(\delta_{kp}\delta_{\ell q}) \\
 &= \delta_{ip}X^2_{q\ell}
  + X_{ip}X_{q\ell}
  + X^2_{ip}\delta_{\ell q} \\
}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me what is that dot symbol inside the circle to look it up? Also, about the notation $X^b = vec(X)$? Its the Kronecker product, right?

Comment: It's the Kronecker product and it's in the Wikipedia article linked in your question, after the opening paragraph. Did you read it yet?  Also, $X^b$ is not a standard notation. It looks like the author just made it up.

Comment: When I first commented I remember seeing it somewhere so I went back to the link to check and found, thus editing my previous comment. It's possible that he made it up, I haven't found it elsewhere yet. I will use your method to calculate one of his results and if it works I accept your answer.

Comment: Could you please tell me if my example is correct? Let $F = c^TXc$. Then $dF = c^TdXc \implies \text{vec}(dF) = c^T \otimes c\text{vec}(dX) \implies \frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(X)}
 = c^T \otimes c$?

Comment: Wait, your question said $F$ was matrix-valued, but in this example it's scalar-valued. Technically, you can treat it as a $1\times 1$ matrix, in which case the gradient is $c^T\otimes c^T.\;$  Looks like you accidentally dropped the transpose on the first vector when you did the vec operation.

Comment: A better example to show how the vec operation works is $${\rm vec}(a^T\,dX\,b) = (b^T\otimes a^T)\,{\rm vec}(dX)$$

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I forgot the transpose. I took it as an example because it seemed the easier one to calculate from the ones the author used. But the result is $(cc^T)^b$ so  they don't agree.

Comment: But they do agree! Simply slip a $(1\times 1)$ 
identity matrix between the two vectors and then vectorize it
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(ab^T) 
  &= {\rm vec}(a\cdot [1]\cdot b^T) \\
  &= (b\otimes a)\cdot{\rm vec}([1]) \\
  &= (b\otimes a) \\
}$$
The final transpose reflects the author's preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)

Comment: You are right! Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I had a similar question. Thanks for your answer.