# Let $T:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be defined by $T(X)=A^2X+AXA+XA^2$ for some $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be defined by $T(X)=A^2X+AXA+XA^2$ for some $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Then $T$ is a linear operator. The problem is that can we explicitly obtain the kernel of this linear map. If $A$ is a singular matrix then $X=xy^*$ satisfies $T(X)=0$ where $Ax=0$ and $y^*A=0$. But there exists matrix $A$ for which there is no connection between $A$ and $X$ for example if $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad X=\begin{pmatrix}
    0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&2&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So how we can obtain the kernel of $T$ completely.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. For one, anyone can see the post's [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4644191/revisions) and find out its original content. Since you can't delete your question if it has an upvoted answer, the proper way of doing this is to flag for moderator attention and get them to handle the question according to [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34761/what-should-we-do-when-posts-look-too-much-like-an-exam-question).

Comment: Do *not* vandalize your question.  Once you post a question to Math SE, it becomes the property of the *community*.  Your efforts to vandalize this question the efforts which others have made to help you to answer the question, and deprive future users of whatever utility this question has.

Answer (score 4):

[Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is the right tool for analysing such issues. Here is how.

Let us begin by writing

$$T(X)=T_A(X)=A^2X+AXA+XA^2\tag{1}$$

in a different way, using the "vec" operator stacking the columns of any $3 \times 3$ matrix  into a single $9 \times 1$ column vector :

$$T(\operatorname{vec}(X))=\operatorname{vec}(A^2XI)+\operatorname{vec}(AXA)+\operatorname{vec}(IXA^2) \tag{3}$$

Now, if you are already familiar with Kronecker product, let us recall the fundamental identity :

$$\operatorname{vec}(AXB)=(B^T \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(X)\tag{4}$$

Using (4) and denoting $\mathbf{X}=\operatorname{vec}(X)$, (3) can be transformed into  :

$$T(\mathbf{X})=(I \otimes (A^2))\mathbf{X}+(A^T \otimes A)\mathbf{X}+((A^2)^T \otimes I)\mathbf{X}$$

Otherwise said :

$$T(\mathbf{X})=\underbrace{((I \otimes (A^2))+(A^T \otimes A)+((A^2)^T \otimes I))}_{\mathbf{T}}\mathbf{X}\tag{5}$$

Otherwise said, operator $T$ is completely described by $9 \times 9$ matrix $\mathbf{T}$.

For example, if

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{giving} \ A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$\mathbf{T}$ is the sum of the following $9 \times 9$ matrices:

$$\mathbf{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^2&0&0\\0&A^2&0\\0&0&A^2
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
0&A&0\\0&0&A\\A&0&0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&I\\I&0&0\\0&I&0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^2&A&I\\I&A^2&A\\A&I&A^2
\end{pmatrix}\tag{6}$$

How is all this connected with the initial question, obtaining the kernel of operator $T$ defined by (1) ?

Plainly, by finding the kernel of $\mathbf{T}$, then doing the inverse operation of $vec$, i.e., by "reshaping" all $9 \times 1$ column vectors constituting a basis of this kernel into $3 \times 3$ matrices.

**Remark :** In initial expression (1), $T(X)$ can be considered as the differential computed in $A$ of function $C$ defined by $C(X)=X^3$. I am almost sure that properties of operator $T$ can be deduced from this fact.

**Edit :** Having done extensive numerical simulations (using Matlab), I have found pairs :

$$(A,X) \ \text{solutions of eq. } T_A(X)=0$$

(see equ. (1)) where *both* $A$ and $X$ have full rank.

Here is a particularily interesting instance (see explanation below) :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&-2\\2&0& \ \ 1\\2&1& \ \ 1
\end{pmatrix}, \ \ X=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&-1\\1&1&1\\1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Please note that $A$ is specific because $A^3=-3I_3$...

A remarkable fact is that for this choice of $A$, the kernel of $9 \times 9$ matrix $\mathbf{T}$ has dimension $6$ ! Moreover, we can exhibit a basis with $6$ elements of this kernel. Indeed, instead of matrix $X=X_1$ above, we could have taken one of the other five matrices :

$$X_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&1\\1&1&-2\\1&0&-2
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{or} \ X_3=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&-1&1\\1&2&-1\\2&2&0
\end{pmatrix}  \ \text{or} $$

$$X_4=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&-1\\1&1&1\\0&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}   \ \text{or} \ X_5=\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0\\-2&-1&1\\0&2&-1
\end{pmatrix}   \ \text{or}$$

$$X_6=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-2&1\\-1&-1&1\\0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}, $$

One can check that all the $X_k, \  k=1,2 \cdots 6$ are full-rank matrices and that they constitute a basis of the kernel of $T_A$.

Of course, one can get, by combining these $X_k$, other matrices $X$ belonging to the kernel of $T£ which are rank-2 or even rank-1.

Comment: About the last remark see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841051/305862).