# Does there exist a way to compute matrix "properties" (eigenvalues, determinant, etc.) from its vectorized representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

I am wondering whether there are some formulas that compute matrix eigenvalues, determinant, rank, etc. directly from its vectorized representation.

More formally: suppose $\bf S \in \mathbb{S}^N$, i.e. square and symmetric. We can represent *any* matrix with its vectorized form $\bf s= \operatorname{vec(\bf S)} \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2}$, i.e. by storing all its entries in a vector. At this point we can perform operations involving $\bf S$, by equivalently using $\bf s$. Simple example:
$$\operatorname{trace}(\bf A^\top \bf S) = \sum_{i,j}A_{ij} S_{ij}= \operatorname{vec(\bf A)}^\top \operatorname{vec(\bf S)}= \bf a ^\top \bf s$$

This makes sense clearly.

**Question 1:** My first question stems from the fact that we have clearly the same information in $\bf s$ as in $\bf S$, we are not losing anything if not the structure. Can we then compute, say, the eigenvalues of $\bf S$ from $\bf s$ without reshaping it? At the end, they are function of the entries of $\bf S$.

**Question 2:** If the answer to the above question is yes, then another fundamental question is whether we can perform the same operation in the half-vectorization space of the matrix, i.e. the vector storing only its lower (or upper) triangular part, for a symmetric matrix. Again, we are not losing any information.

An affirmative answer to the above question is important, for instance, in algorithms where the use of vectors reduces the dimensionality of the problem at hand, but where matrix properties are necessary.
Thank you

**EDIT**: to make the context more clear. I am implementing an iterative algorithm working with the independent variables of the matrix only. I need to  perform an SVD to shrink the singular values at every iteration. I am wondering whether I can perform such operation without reshaping the matrix and then reshape back to a vector.

Comment: Reshaping the matrix is not expensive, it is essentially free in most languages. Computing the SVD can be expensive. An Eigenvalue Decomposition (EVD) can be a bit (30%) faster for symmetric matrices. But if you require all of those singular values, then you must pay the computational price.  The library routines for SVD are very mature; I doubt you'll be able to improve upon them using half-vec tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, but what about memory? Having a $N(N-1)/2$ vector instead of a $N^2$ matrix can in many cases make a difference, although it's nor order of magnitudes. But if such solution by working in the half-vec space would exists, the code itself would be more clean without all these lifting..

Comment: Yes, you will save space storing the matrix in compressed form. And you can do simple arithmetic (addition, multiplication) using the compact form. But in order to calculate the singular values you'll need to pass the full matrix to the SVD (or EVD) subroutine. If your laptop can't handle it, it doesn't cost that much to spin up an Amazon/AWS instance for a few minutes.

Comment: True, that may be an option as well. So the answer to my question I guess is: " no, you cannot compute eigenvalues (end eigenvectors) without reshaping". Is that correct? In that case, it may be interesting to check. 
If we write down the Hessian of a function in the half-vec space, you most likely end up with a Kronecker product of two matrices of dimension $N^2$, hence requiring $N^4$ memory-side ($X \otimes X$). Being able to perform operation directly in the half-vec without reshaping may avoid such issues. Can we half-vectorize it again being symmetric?

Comment: Yes, the duplication matrix $\big(x={\rm vech}(X)\implies X=Dx\big)$ is sparse, therefore $(D\otimes D)$ is also sparse. So you could write $(X\otimes X)=(D\otimes D)(x\otimes x)$. The LHS requires storage $\sim N^4$ while the RHS requires only $\sim \tfrac 14 N^4.\;$ But this won't help you calculate the eigenvalues.

Comment: Isn't the duplication matrix $D$ used to restore $vec(X)= Dvech(X)$? Are you referring to another $D$ I suppose?

Comment: Nope, I was _thinking_ of the standard duplication matrix but the equations I _wrote_ are for a third-order duplication tensor.  Anyway, the point of the exercise was to estimate how much memory could be saved (roughly a factor of 4). But the implementation gets so tricky that you're better off using standard linear algebra and a big AWS machine.

Comment: Clear. Out of the scope of this question: may I ask whether you are an academic (active or in the past)?

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the same information is there in either representation, so any property can be computed from either representation.

You are asking about whether there are efficiencies to be had choosing one representation over the other. I think the answer is "it depends". In algorithm design and implementation there are always tradeoffs to be made between work done on the data structure and work done in the procedural code. The balance will be different in different computations.

Comment: I need to compute an SVD for instance, and threshold the negative eigenvalues. Reshaping the matrix and compute the SVD is expensive. I am wondering whether I can manipulate directly the vector for instance

Comment: That's a particular algorithm question, not the general one you asked here. I suspect that SVD and eigenvalue calculations have been well explored and that the most efficient algorithms are in the literature and implemented. I see several in a search for _svd calclations_.

Comment: This discussion is pointless, as the compiler will anyway reshape the matrices in vectors.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I more or less agree that the discussion is pointless, but not quite for the same reason. The compiler's reshaping may not be the most efficient for algorithm access to the elements, which might be improved by deciding the reshaping at the program level.

Comment: @EthanBolker: do you have any example in mind ? This would only work smoothly for row-by-row processing, which is pretty rare in matrix computation. First counter-example is matrix multiplication (or just matrix transposition).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've no particular example, just the general principle, which is why my answer suggests that the question is much too broad. The OP will have to search for a useful answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you both for your answers. Actually, I don't know whether I conveyed the message in a different way than expected. My motivation is not on how to store, retrieve elements of the matrix. My motivation arises from the fact I am implementing an algorithm that works with vectorized matrix forms, kind of gradient descent with only independent variables of the matrix. For each iteration I need to perform an SVD of this matrix to threshold some of the eigenvalues. I was then wondering whether it is possible to perform such operation already in the lower dimensional vector space

Comment: @VanBaffo: I would like to know more about the context in which you are interested in matrix calculus. Is there a way I could e-mail you ?